# How to auto mount encrypted USB sticks after hibernate?

Tags: usb, sleep-wake, encryption, mount, hibernate

I use 2 tiny USB sticks as extra storage space on my Mac. When I close the lid, I send the Mac to hibernate mode. Is there a way such that I auto mount the encrypted USB sticks right after I unlock the Mac?

What I currently do, is simply detach and put in again the USB sticks, so they are automatically mounted and decrypted. But that is obviously pretty annoying.

Comment: It might be helpful if you'd add to your post the steps to how we could reproduce your situation.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Unfortunately, I am not pretty sure what exactly to do. To describe my situation you could imagine, I have USB sticks attached to my Mac (I never want to take them out) and I boot my MacBook Air (which was turned off). Now, I would like to have the decrypted USB sticks right in the finder after I log in to my account. Not sure whether this clarifies my point... I hope, it does.

Comment: Herein lies the issues with what you described in your comment. If I start my MacBook Pro with an encrypted USB drive attached, it's mounted and ready to access via Finder once OS X has booted to the Desktop. Or when having `hibernate mode` set to `25`vs. the default `3` and coming back from being hibernated it's the same result as in my opening sentence of this comment. I'm assuming because its password is stored in my Keychain. So without explicit and specific details surrounding all aspects on the issue I'm not going to waste any time trying to figure out what's not working for you, sorry.

Comment: Ok given your comment, I try to be more precise again: I use Macbook Air 11 (2015) with OS X 10.11.6. I have hibernate mode set to 25, rather than the default 3. But I guess thats just the same as starting up the machine after it has been powered off. Anyway, I have hibernate set to 25. After I wake up the machine, I just told that the devices have not correctly been unmounted. Then they remain unmounted. Even though, I have all passwords in the keychain. Regards

Comment: Okay, that should have been included in the original post. I too get that same error however my encrypted USB drive gets mounted. This is under OS X 10.8.5 and may be different depending on which version of OS X you're running. You should edit your post and include all of this information, as comments can get deleted. That said, since I can't reproduce your issue I can only offer a workaround in the form of a way to more easily mount the drives without having to unplug and put back in. This assumes they can be seen by `diskutil` after waking from hibernation thought, if you're interested.

Comment: Because the USB disk are not properly unmounted when`hibernate mode` is set to `25`, I'd say that due to the nature of `hibernate mode` being set to `25` all external disks should be ejected before invoking hibernation. Therefore, if you first eject the USB disks without physically removing them, do they auto mount without issue then coming back from hibernation or is it just no error message and no auto mounting?

Comment: In fact, if I eject them manually, they are properly started the next time the machine wakes up. That's a great hint! But is there an easy way of ejecting automatically before sending to hibernate 25?

Comment: Please define what an _easy_ use case scenario would be for you with this issue.

Comment: I think it would perfectly fit my use case. And probably others might face the same issue... It's just that I won't eject usb devices manually every time I close the lid. I hope this question makes sense...

Answer (score -1):

You can use a program called ControlPlane to automatically eject your USB drives when the system going to sleep.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the software you recommended is better than others out there.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, find the software and evaluate it themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review